# Suma con Condición SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
 T1.REF,
 FORMAT(T1.EMISION, 'dd/MM/yyyy') EMISION,
 FORMAT(T1.SUBASTA, 'dd/MM/yyyy') SUBASTA,
 T1.OPERACION,
 T1.NIVEL,
 T1.METODO,
 '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(T1.MONTO_EMISION AS MONEY),1)) MONTO_EMISION,
 '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(T1.CAPTURA AS MONEY),1)) CAPTURA,
 '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST((T1.CAPTURA - T1.MONTO_EMISION) AS MONEY),1)) SOBRA,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.SPINOFF) + '%' SPINOFF,
 '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(T1.MONTO_SP AS MONEY),1)) MONTO_SP,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.SOBRETASA) + '%' SOBRETASA,
 T1.DXV,
 T1.FEE_BPS,
 '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(T1.MONTO_CONVOCADO AS MONEY),1)) MONTO_CONVOCADO,
 '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(T1.MONTO_DEMANDADO AS MONEY),1)) MONTO_DEMANDADO,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.TASA_MAXIMA) + '%' TASA_MAXIMA,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.TASA_MINIMA) + '%' TASA_MINIMA,
 T1.MONEDA,
 T1.TASA_REF,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.TASA_BASE) + '%' TASA_BASE,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.TASA_ALL_IN) + '%' TASA_ALL_IN
FROM
(SELECT
    A.REF,
    A.EMISION,
    A.SUBASTA,
    A.OPERACION,
    A.NIVEL,
    A.METODO,
    A.MONTO_EMISION,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.TIPO IN ('Monto','Spinoff') THEN B.VALOR_OFRECIDO ELSE 0 END) AS CAPTURA,
    (A.SPINOFF * 100) SPINOFF,
    (A.MONTO_EMISION * (A.SPINOFF / 100)) MONTO_SP,
    (A.SOBRETASA * 100) SOBRETASA,
    A.DXV,
    A.FEE_BPS,
    A.MONTO_CONVOCADO,
    A.MONTO_DEMANDADO,
    (A.TASA_MAXIMA * 100) TASA_MAXIMA,
    (A.TASA_MINIMA * 100) TASA_MINIMA,
    A.MONEDA,
    A.TASA_REF,
    (A.TASA_BASE * 100) TASA_BASE,
    ((A.TASA_BASE + A.SOBRETASA) * 100) TASA_ALL_IN
 FROM TDASHBOARD A
 LEFT JOIN TBITACORA B ON A.REF = B.REF
 GROUP BY A.REF,A.EMISION,A.SUBASTA,A.OPERACION,A.NIVEL,A.METODO,A.MONTO_EMISION,B.TIPO ,A.SPINOFF,A.SOBRETASA,A.DXV,A.FEE_BPS,A.MONTO_CONVOCADO,A.MONTO_DEMANDADO,
    A.TASA_MAXIMA,A.TASA_MINIMA,A.MONEDA,A.TASA_REF,A.TASA_BASE
 )T1
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

B.TIPO contiene: Monto, Spinoff y Porcentaje: intento suma total cuando B.TIPO contenga Monto y Spinoff pero al parecer el LEFT JOIN me devuelve 0 en la columna CAPTURA en aquellos cuando B.TIPO contiene porcentaje duplicándome la Referencia.

Como puedo condicionar la suma para que no duplique la referencia, aclaro que hay referencias como la 3,4,etc que no tienen registros en TBITACORA y por lo tanto dan 0 o NULL en la columna CAPTURA

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas agrupando por B.TIPO

```
GROUP BY A.REF,A.EMISION,A.SUBASTA,A.OPERACION,A.NIVEL,A.METODO,A.MONTO_EMISION,B.TIPO
```

Quítalo de la agrupación

Comment: Si de acuerdo, funciona a la perfección. Gracias